# How can I implement screen tapping functionality programmatically in Flutter to simulate user clicks?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, stack-overflow

screen tapping functionality programmatically auto click, multi click
programmatically "I'm working on a Flutter application and I'm trying to implement a screen tapping or auto-clicking functionality. I've been exploring different approaches but haven't found a suitable solution yet. Could someone provide me with hints, suggestions, or code examples on how to implement this functionality in Flutter? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated."

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is it specifically that you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.